# Write a sed command to extract words

Tags: shell, sed

There is a file from which  i want to get

```
libqt4-dbus   
libqt4-network   
libqt4-script   
libqt4-test   
libqt4-xml   
libqtcore4   
libqt4-designer   
libqt4-opengl   
libqt4-svg   
libqtgui4
```

How can i write a sed command such as  `sed 's/    /'  test`

Here is the file  named test

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

> libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but
>   4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
>                  Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
>                  Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
>                  Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed    libqt4-gui : Depends:
>   libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be
>   installed
>                 Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
>                 Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed

Comment: if you want to distinguish between lines that say "not going to be installed" and "is going to be installed", you'll need to modify the text of your question. Good luck.

Comment: will the "Depends each be on seperate lines? you might have a chance at it being easy then. Also does it need to be sed?

Comment: Is the `libqt4-gui` and `libqt4-designer` information really on the same line as the `libqt4core` information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is some sort of formatting glitch at:

```
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
```

(so in fact it probably reads:

```
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
```

) then this should do:

```
sed 's/.*Depends: \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' lib-dep-list
```

Given data file `lib-dep-list`:

```
libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-10) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2 is to be installed
```

The output is:

```
libqt4-dbus
libqt4-network
libqt4-script
libqt4-test
libqt4-xml
libqtcore4
libqt4-designer
libqt4-opengl
libqt4-svg
libqtgui4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
 awk -v RS="Depends:" 'NR>1{print $1}' temp.txt
```